# Get string translations of all present localisations

Tags: ios, swiftui, localization

I need check if some string exists in any localisation without changing current locale of application.

Swiftui, iOS app.

I use NSLocalizedString(), but there no way to set language for translation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach in SwiftUI, to `Get string translations of all present localisations`,

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let txt = "some text here"
    let filesPaths = Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: "lproj", inDirectory: nil)
    
    var body: some View {
        List(filesPaths, id: \.self) { path in
            Text(Bundle(path: path)?.localizedString(forKey: txt, value: nil, table: nil) ?? "no data")
        }
    }
}
```